# Terminating app, reason: 'containerIdentifier can not be nil' terminating with uncaught exception of type CKException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I'm new with Swift.
And I have my first project with CloudKit.
But unfortunately I get a error wit getting data from CloudKit:

I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'containerIdentifier can not be nil'
terminating with uncaught exception of type CKException
```

With this code:

```
import Foundation
import CloudKit

class CKRelation {
    static let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    class func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<[Relation], Error>) -> ()) {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let name = NSSortDescriptor(key: "LastName", ascending: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Clients", predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [name]

        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        operation.desiredKeys = ["FirstName", "Initials", "LastName", "MiddleName", "RelationId"]
        operation.resultsLimit = 50

        var newRelations = [Relation]()

        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
            var relation = Relation()
            relation.recordID = record.recordID
            relation.FirstName = record["FirstName"] as! String
            relation.Initials = record["Initials"] as! String
            relation.LastName = record["LastName"] as! String
            relation.MiddleName = record["MiddleName"] as! String
            relation.RelationId = record["RelationId"] as! Int
            
            newRelations.append(relation)
        }

        operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                } else {
                    completion(.success(newRelations))
                    print("data")
                }
            }
        }
        database.add(operation)
    }
```

I can not find anything on the internet. Hopefully somebody can help me.

Comment: Whats your icloud containerIdentifier? It's set in app capabilities (enable iCloud). https://cocoacasts.com/a-primer-on-cloudkit-containers-and-databases

Comment: "I get this error"  If somebody says the same thing, you say what?  Where!?  At what line?

Comment: @MarekH Thanks for the reply. The app is enabled on the correct CloudKit container. The link you sent I will definitely read, I think there is a lot of useful information in there. Do you perhaps have any other ideas as to what the issue is?

Comment: @ElTomato je hebt helemaal gelijk. Op lijn 12 is de fout: 
'static let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase'

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too, because my project didn't establish the database for CloudKit.
Follow Apple's demo, can solve the problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSyUV.png)

Comment: Please [edit] and post code as test, not image.

Comment: Adding code can add context to your answer and make it easier for people to understand. And, it makes it better because instead of trusting that you're right and reading the docs at the link you provided to find out how you're right, we can just read your answer and determine it from here. In general it is bad practice to leave a link as your answer.